# Flutter fcm redirect issue

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi in one of my flutter project, I am using firebase messaging. First a splash screen and second, the main page of the application. In second page, I implemented the `firebase.configure` method in the `init state` as follows. The `_navigateToItemDetail` method leads to an another page

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        setState(() {
          _newNotification = true;
        });
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        _navigateToItemDetail(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        _navigateToItemDetail(message);
      },
    );
```

and I cam calling the web service for this page after this. But the above method will launch after the webservice calls. So that will cause error in the page redirection. I just put a delay of 4 seconds in web service call, then it will works fine. Is there is any method to solve the issue ? `async` method available for firebase config ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 'onBackgroundMessage'

```
firebaseMessaging.configure(
//...
 onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isIOS ? null : myBackgroundMessageHandler
//...
)


//...
static Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
//Do here something
}
```

as you can see, it only work on android

Comment: so we don't to implement onResume and onLaunch ? Can I handle the redirection inside myBackgroundMessageHandler ?